# Getting innerHTML of a span child element and inserting by id

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code example and looking to extract the contents of the span element "(2)" and insert it into an element id using JavaScript. Here is the HTML code example:

```js
function countTest() {
  let span = getElementById("spanID").getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML
  document.getElementById("placeSpanVAR").innerHTML = span;
}
```

```html
<script src="countTest.js"></script>

<tbody id="spanID">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-gb">
      <a href="javascript:" onclick=""></a>
      <span>(2)</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<br>
<p id="placeSpanVAR"></p>

<body onload="countTest()">
```

Can someone help me understand why this is not working and perhaps what might?

Comment: You're missing the `document` in `let span = getElementById("spanID")`. Also, why is your body element after the rest of your code?

Comment: Your markup is a mess. You have a table body with no table, a paragraph as an apparent table child, and all of that outside the body. Please use a good editor or an HTML validator. Also, don't use line breaks for spacing. Use margin or padding.

Comment: I understand the markup is a mess. This is code coming from a SharePoint classic site and I am pulling the elements out to try to be able to extract contents of the span tag. The code within the <tbody> tags is almost exact though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, getElementById is a method that belongs to the document object. So, you need to do `document.getElementById()` or `document.getElementsByTagName()` for it to work.

If you want to extract the content of the span, I would suggest this to make it easier.

1. Give the span you want to extract the content from an "id". So you can query for it in the easiest way possible `<span id="theSpan">2</span>`
2. Query for the span and query for the p tag you want to insert the html on. `const spanTag = document.getElementById("theSpan").innerHTML` and `let pTag = document.getElementById("placeSpanVAR")`
3. Then just assign the HTML content of spanTag to pTag `pTag = span

I left a snippet for you and it works! Have a good one

```js
const spanContent = document.getElementById("theSpan").innerHTML
let p = document.getElementById("placeSpanVAR")
p = spanContent
console.log(p)
```

```html
<tbody id="spanID">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-gb">
            <a href="javascript:" onclick=""></a>
                <span id="theSpan">(2)</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<br>
    <p id="placeSpanVAR"></p>
```

`

Comment: Thank you. Leaving out the document object was a silly mistake on my end. This is for s SharePoint classic site and the code is generated and wonky. The span does not have an ID nor can I place an ID in it. I am trying to extract the span content by using using the parent ID then the "getElementsByTagName" but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in the code. Here is the updated code. Try that:-

```js
function countTest() {
  let span = document.getElementById("spanID").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("placeSpanVAR").innerHTML = span;
}
```

```html
<script src="countTest.js"></script>
<body onload="countTest()">
<table>
<tbody id="spanID">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-gb">
      <a href="javascript:" onclick=""></a>
      <span>(2)</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<p id="placeSpanVAR"></p>

</body>
```

Remember that, [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), are methods of [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface. So you have to write document. with these methods.